# Disable virtual keyboard while scrolling

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm using delphi rio 10.3.2, on a new firemonkey project for android.

I have form -> tvertscrollbox -> some tedit

if I start scrolling and I tap on e tedit immediatly the virtual keyboard pops up and stop the scrolling.

Is there a way to avoid that? I do not want to see the virtual keyboard if I'm scrolling.

Thank you!

Comment: You can show and hide the virtual keyboard whenever you like. Of course, if you hide it when scrolling starts, you'll also have to show it when it's needed for editing again.

Comment: You might be able to do something similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57458554/3164070. I have not tried it for a TEdit as yet

Comment: I like the idea of disabling keyboard when scrolling start, and disabling when it ends. Do you know a way to do that? Otherwise I will try what @DaveNottage proposes..I was hoping for a simpler solution

Comment: @lorife The problem with that is that scrolling won't actually start if the first contact is on an edit in the scrollbox. If the first contact is on a vacant area of the scrollbox, it will scroll and the virtual keyboard won't show anyway

Comment: thank you. well I hope embarcadero will fix that in future.